# Condensing a long if statement to a short one automatically

Tags: python, algorithm, if-statement

Lets say we have an if statement in python of form:

if a == 1 or a == 2 or a == 3 ... a == 100000 for a large number of comparisons, all connected with an or.

What would a good algorithm be to compress that into a smaller if statement?
eg for the above

if a >= 1 and a <= 100000

Sometimes there will be a pattern in the numbers and sometimes they will be completely random so the algorithm must deal well with both cases.

Can anyone suggest a decent algorithm that will efficiently condense an if statement of this form?

Edit: The goal is to have the resulting if statement be as short as possible. The efficiency of evaluating the if statement is secondary to length.

Comment: You mean 1 <= a <= 100000 ?

Comment: If you show some work on this, you're likely to get some better answers

Comment: You want something that will parse the code, detect the complex statement, and optimize it? What if it's something like `if a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 3 || a == 100 || a == 101 || a == 102`? Do you want to optimize to `if ((a >= 1 && a <= 3) || (a >= 100 && a <= 102))`? Just how "optimum" do you want this?

Comment: You could perhaps get some ideas by looking into how C/C++/Java/whatever compilers optimize `switch` statements.

Comment: @SteveJessop, thanks God - we're working in Python

Answer (score 3):

If there is no pattern in your numbers, you can use a tuple and use membership test

```
if a in (1,2,3,... 100000)
```

Comment: But this may be inefficient if there are large runs of consecutive numbers.

Comment: Then use a set instead. Testing if a number is part of a set is done in O(1).

Comment: @Dyrborg But creating the set in the first place is still O(n).

Comment: But if he is trying to optimize code like this, I assume, once optimized, that this piece of code will be reached more than once - hence it is much more efficient to create a set in O(n) time to allow all subsequent matches to run in O(1) time - instead of doing it in O(n) for every comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You sort your "compare list", then traverse it to extract runs of consecutive integers as separate intervals. For intervals of length 1 (i.e. single numbers) you perform an `==` test and for larger intervals you can perform the chained `=<`/`>=` comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a sorted array of numbers to compare and perform binary search on it whenever you want to check for a . If a exists in array then the statement is true else false. It will be O(logn) for each if query

Answer (score 0):

a quick and easy way is:

```
if a in set(pattern in the numbers and sometimes they will be completely random):
   whaterver
```

You can also given

```
x = random.sample(xrange(100), 30)
```

you could build up a list of ranges:

```
for i in x:
    if  ranges and i-1 in ranges[-1]:
        ranges[-1].append(i)
    else:
        if ranges: ranges[-1] = ranges[-1][0], ranges[-1][-1]
        ranges.append([i])
```

tidy the ranges up and then then loop through it

```
for range in ranges:
    if range[0] <= a <= range[0]:
       whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

What works in the least space for the if statement is going to be a test for membership in a set of values. (Don't use a tuple or a list for this - this is what sets are for):

```
if a in set_of_numbers:
    blah ...
```

If you know from your wider problem that when expressed as ranges of integers, that you will usually have sufficiently less ranges to compare, then you can use code from the Rosetta Code [Range extraction](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Range_extraction#Python) task to create the ranges, with a different print routine `printi` to format the output as a for statement:

```
def printi(ranges):
    print( 'if %s:' % 
           ' or '.join( (('%i<=a<=%i' % r) if len(r) == 2 else 'a==%i' % r)
                     for r in ranges ) )
```

For the Rosetta code example numbers it will produce the following:

```
if 0<=a<=2 or a==4 or 6<=a<=8 or a==11 or a==12 or 14<=a<=25 or 27<=a<=33 or 35<=a<=39:
```

**Tradeoffs**

1. For a few but large ranges then a large set would have to be created in your source against a more compact creation of the if statement comparing explicit ranges.
2. For many scattered ranges the if statement becomes very long - the set solution would be easier to maintain - still long but probably easier to scan.

I don't know your full problem, but probably the best way to handle this is if the integers come in a file that is easy to parse then make your program parse this file and create an appropriate set or list of ranges on the fly for your if statement.